# Landau-Ginzburg theory vs. Landau theory for phase transitions

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, terminology, definition, phase-transition

I would like a clarification on the difference between [Landau-Ginzburg theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ginzburg%E2%80%93Landau_theory) and [Landau theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_theory) for phase transitions. On one hand, I see some books present the Landau-Ginzburg as a general approach to analyse phase transitions, which is pretty similar to Landau theory.

But on the other hand, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ginzburg%E2%80%93Landau_theory) presents Landau-Ginzburg theory as a pure technique for superconductivity. This left me a little bit confused as to what is the difference between the two.

Comment: Section 5.4 of [these notes](https://dec41.user.srcf.net/notes/II_L/statistical_physics.pdf) goes into the difference.

Comment: @bolbteppa thank you for sharing with me this. So according to my understanding both of those theories trying to describe general approach to only *magnetic* systems? those theories  has nothing to do in liquid gas phase transition for example?

Comment: The start of Sec.5 says they are looking at Liquid-Gas vs. Ising phase transitions and that "these two examples should be rather unrelated to each other, but it turns out they behave in a very similar way.  In fact, it seems like all phase transitions look somewhat alike", then at in 5.4, Landau's theory, it says it is trying to abstract the similar properties into a general theory of phase transitions, Ginzburg comes along and points out stuff Landau missed, some of which wasn't fixed until Wilson, as pointed out in the first two pages [here](https://users.ox.ac.uk/~phys1116/msm-rg2.pdf).

Comment: I agree, but in section 5.4, he trying to base his theory on the Ising model. I did not see relation to liquid - gas phase transition. So this is not clear for me how to infer from this theory about the phase transition of liquid- gas

Comment: The very last page (p.125) discusses liquid-gas in a way that lets you see why it looks like they are generalizing only Ising at the beginning.